# Comment Migration Resurrects the Dead

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-abilities

If an answer had a comment that was deleted, and a ♦ converts the answer with its comments to a comment, the deleted comment reappears.

Interestingly, the checkbox only appears if there is at least one *live* comment.

Comment: 2nd temporary​​ ​​​​​​​​​answer

Comment: This comment was ♦-deleted.

Comment: Normal comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: I confirmed that it's fixed.